# Load Obj file and measurement Tool

Tags: three.js

I loaded an obj file successfully, but I am trying to add a measurement tool by mark the 3d model with two points and draw a straight line between them. something like Potree (unfortunately, it doesn't support .obj files). How can do that as I am using three.js.

Comment: Post what you have already tried

Comment: I need to do something like this : http://3dhop.net/examples/demos/8.0_measurement_tool.php?title=Measurement%20Tool (unfortunately, this tools doesn't support .obj files yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a `mousedown` listener
2. Raycast from the `camera` to the mouse position
3. Save intersection point A, B as `Vector3`
4. Calculate distance between A, B

Shortened Code:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector2();
    vector.set(
        ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
        - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1 );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, camera );  

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( model.children );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        pointA = intersects[ 0 ].point;
        // some logic to save pointB
        // on the second click...
        //pointB = intersects[ 0 ].point;

        var distance = pointA.distanceTo( pointB );

        // draw Line
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push( pointA );
        geometry.vertices.push( pointB );
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
        line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
        scene.add(line);

    }
}
```

Working example, distance output is in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/kgxs7afv/1/

Three.js r107